# How can Linux service installation page create an attack surface?

Tags: linux, audit, hardening, attack-surface

Based on one of the lectures of Planning, Auditing and Maintaining Enterprise system course  by Greg Williams (Department of computer science university of Colorado):

> Let's say they were installing a service on a Linux system and we forget to take down the installation page. That installation page has a lot of sensitive information on it. so, if we leave that page up and don't delete it out of the directory after installation, that's a way for an attacker to get in.

How It becomes possible?

Comment: Seems vague and misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"that's a way" requires an antecedent, and it is very vague.

The page being up? No, that doesn't offer a way in. It's static.

The information on the page? If the info helps someone to craft a way in, sure, but then the information isn't the way in, it's merely a resource.

I think this is simply a case of someone not being careful when speaking.